# AWK NR Variable Syntax Issue

Tags: bash, awk

I am new to AWK and trying to write some code where I can delete all files in a directory apart from the newest N number.
My code works if I use a hard coded number instead of a variable.
Works:

```
delete=`ls -t | awk 'NR>3'`
echo $delete
```

Does Not Work:

```
 amount=3
 delete=`ls -t | awk 'NR>$amount'`
 echo $delete
```

I know the problem lies somewhere with the bash variable not being recognised as an awk variable however I do not know how to correct.
I have tried variations of code to fix this such as below, however I am still at a loss.

```
amount=3
delete=`ls -t | awk -v VAR=${amount} 'NR>VAR'`
echo $delete
```

Could you please advise what the correct code is ?

Comment: your code works for me. my OS is centOS 6.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shells don't expand anything inside single quotes.

Either:

```
amount=3
delete=$(ls -t | awk "NR>$amount")
```

or:

```
amount=3
delete=$(ls -t | awk -v amount=$amount 'NR > amount')
```

Be aware that parsing the output of `ls` is fraught if your file names are not limited to the portable file name character set.  Spaces, newlines, and other special characters in the file name can wreck the parsing.

Comment: But the second snippet is essentially the same as the last example in the OP. Why would one work and not the other?

Comment: @user000001: I don't know what went wrong with the user's own version; it should have worked.  I'd guess a typo, but I'm not privy to the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is to use double quotes instead of single.  Single quotes prevent the shell from interpolating the variable `$amount` in the quoted string.

```
amount=3
ls -t | awk "NR>$amount"
```

I would not use a variable to capture the result.  If you do use one, you need to quote it properly when interpolating it.

```
amount=3
delete=$(ls -t | awk -v VAR="$amount" 'NR>VAR')
echo "$delete"
```

Note that this is basically identical to your second attempt, which should have worked, modulo the string quoting issues.